# Create an Object, pass the Object to another Object's constructor, call wait() on Object, then notify() in Java

Tags: java, sockets, wait, notify

I'm trying to handle multiple connections on the same port of my server. I'm doing this by instantiating an Object and passing it into the constructor for another class, which implements Runnable. Then I set up a socket in the Runnable class and call notify() on the passed Object after a Client connects on the port. This should then allow the server to restart its loop, creating another instance of the Runnable class after being notified. However, currently the wait() isnt being reached until after the client is closed. Here are the 3 relevant classes I have:

Server class:

```
   package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        HashMap<String, PortDummy> portDummies = new HashMap<String, PortDummy>();
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(;;){
            Object block = new Object();
            PortDummy dummy = new PortDummy(serverSocket, block, portDummies);
            System.out.println("Running dummy port...");
            dummy.start();
            try {
                synchronized(block){
                    System.out.println("Waiting...");
                    block.wait();
                    System.out.println("Block notified.");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Can't be interrupted!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PortDummy (Runnable) class:

```
   package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PortDummy extends Thread {

    private Object block;
    private HashMap<String, PortDummy> portDummies;
    private String clientName = null;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    BufferedReader socketIn;
    PrintWriter socketOut;

    public PortDummy(ServerSocket serverSocket, Object block, HashMap<String, PortDummy> portDummies){
        this.block = block;
        this.portDummies = portDummies;
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting dummy port...");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection made.");
            synchronized(block){
                System.out.print("Notifying...");
                block.notify();
                System.out.println("...done.");
            }

            socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            socketOut = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            String inContent;

            boolean loggedIn = false;
            while((inContent = socketIn.readLine()) != null){   
                socketOut.println("Server Echo: " + inContent);
                if(inContent.startsWith("/exit")){
                    if(loggedIn){
                        portDummies.remove(clientName);
                        System.out.println(clientName + " signed out. Removed from portDummies.");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Closing...");
                    }
                }
                else if(inContent.startsWith("/register")){
                    System.out.println("/register accepted");
                    if(!loggedIn){
                        if(registerUser(inContent)){
                            System.out.println("Successfully registered.");
                            socketOut.println(clientName + " successfully registered.");
                            loggedIn = true;
                        }else{
                            socketOut.print("That user already exists.");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        socketOut.print("Already logged in.");
                    }
                }
                else if(inContent.startsWith("/tell")){
                    if(!loggedIn){
                        socketOut.println("You need to log in.");
                    }
                    else{
                        String[] parts = inContent.split("\\w");
                        String[] withoutCommand = new String[parts.length-1];
                        for(int i = 1; i<parts.length-1; i++){
                            withoutCommand[i] = parts[i];
                        }
                        String[] messageParts = new String[withoutCommand.length-1];
                        String message = "";
                        for(int j = 1; j<withoutCommand.length-1; j++){
                            message += withoutCommand[j] + " ";
                        }

                        String recipient = withoutCommand[0];
                        sendMessage(recipient, message);
                    }
                }
                else if(inContent.startsWith("/help")){
                    socketOut.print("/help ~~~~~~~ List all commands. \n " +
                            "/register <username> ~~~~~~~ Register a new user with 'username'. \n " +
                            "/tell <username> <message> ~~~~~~~ Send 'username' text 'message'. \n " +
                            "/exit ~~~~~~~ Log out.");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Shutting down client connections...");
            socketOut.close();
            socketIn.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            serverSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    private boolean registerUser(String text){
        System.out.println("Registering user...");
        String user = text.substring(10);
        if((user != null) && !(portDummies.containsKey(user))){
            portDummies.put(user, this);
            clientName = user;
            System.out.println(user + " registered.");
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }

    private void sendMessage(String username, String message){
        if(portDummies.containsKey(username)){
            PortDummy recip = portDummies.get(username);
            recip.getSocketOutput().println(clientName + ": " + message);
        }
        else{
            socketOut.write("User " + username + " doesn't exist.");
        }
    }

    public PrintWriter getSocketOutput(){
        return socketOut;
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
package client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Client {

    protected String username;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Socket serverSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
            BufferedReader socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter socketOut = new PrintWriter(serverSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            Scanner keyboardInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String keyboardInput, serverInput;
            System.out.println("Welcome to Chris Volkernick's Server IM Client! \n" +
                    "Type '/register <username>' to register, '/list' to list connected users," +
                    "\n or '/tell <username> <message>' to send a user a message. '/help' lists these commands. (Type '/exit' to sign out.)");
            while((keyboardInput = keyboardInputScanner.nextLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("Input '" + keyboardInput + "' read on client side.");
                if(keyboardInput.equals("/exit")){
                    socketOut.println("/exit");
                    socketOut.close();
                    socketIn.close();
                    serverSocket.close();
                }else{
                    socketOut.println(keyboardInput);

                    while((serverInput = socketIn.readLine()) != null){
                        System.out.println(serverInput);
                    }
                }           
            }       
            keyboardInputScanner.close();

        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IOException!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the wait() and/or notify()?

EDIT: I also tried changing the implements Runnable to extends Thread then changing the .run() in the server to .start(), but that gives me this error:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:97)
    at server.PortDummy.run(PortDummy.java:28)
```

**EDIT 2: It seems to be working the way it should now in terms of starting new threads. However, I'm now running into another problem: After I enter a command on the client side of any given client, I can't enter additional commands. The first command will work fine (minus /exit; haven't quite figured out how that should work yet), just can't do anything after that. For example, I can register (sign in) but after that nothing else. I can go into another instance of Client and list all the current users (works), but again, after that I cannot enter additional commands. Any idea what may be happening to cause this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your child threads are trying to listen on port 8000, but the parent thread is already doing that. What you need to do is pass accept a connection from the original socket and then give it to the child thread. I'm not exactly sure how to do this in Java, but I suspect it's just..

Put this in your main thread:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

And then once you get that, pass `clientSocket` to your `Thread`.

That way there's only one socket listening on port 8000, but you can make child threads handle each connection.

Comment: So what you're saying is, create the original socket in my Server class's main, then pass clientSocket to the PortDummy constructor? What would I do then with the clientSocket in the PortDummy?

Comment: @Chris V. - Basically, do everything in the child threads *except for making the `ServerSocket`*, because only one of those is allowed to exist on a single port.

Comment: Ohhhhh, so you mean the ServerSocket I'm making in the child is redundant..? I think I might get what you're saying, then...

Comment: Could you check out my revised code in my original post and see if I'm understanding you correctly?

Comment: I would suggest putting this line in the main thread: `Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();` and then pass `clientSocket` to the `PortDummy`. That way your loop with block until you have a connection, spawn off a new thread, and then start waiting for connections again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4284/discussion-between-chris-v-and-brendan-long)

Answer (score 0):

When using wait and notify, realize that notifies aren't queued, so if the notify happens before the wait occurs, you will never exit the wait. Therefore you should never perform naked waits, that is there should always be some condition you test to see if you should wait.

```
sychronized(block) {
   while (!available) {
       block.wait();
   }
}
```

and

```
synchronized(block) {
    available = true;
    block.notifyAll();
}
```

etc

Comment: Where is that boolean initialized?

Answer (score 0):

```
package so_7775790;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


/**
 * barebones server -- ctl-C to kill it ;)
 */
public class Server implements Runnable {

    final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getSimpleName());


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int port = 8000;
        final String tname = "my-server-thread";
        final Server server = new Server(port);

        try {
            Thread tserver = new Thread(server, tname);
            tserver.start();
            tserver.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    // -------------------------------------------------
    // server
    // -------------------------------------------------

    final int port;
    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    public void run() {
        try{
            final ServerSocket srvsocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            log.info(String.format("Server started @ %s\n", srvsocket));

            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                Socket newclient = srvsocket.accept();

                // spawn thread and hand off new client to handler
                new Thread(new ClientHandler(newclient)).start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
        }
        log.info("server stopped");
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    // client handler
    // -------------------------------------------------
    static class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        final Socket socket;
        public ClientHandler(final Socket socket) {
            assert socket != null : "serverthread is null";
            this.socket = socket;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override final
        public void run() {
            log.info(String.format("new client @ %s\n", socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()));
            try {
                final InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                final OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

                // NOTE: this is just a stub busy loop!
                for(;;) {
                    /* your protocol impl here .. */
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.severe(e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    log.severe(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```